# UITextFieldDelegate: How to select which methods gets called for each individual TextField

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield

Currently I have a class that conforms to UITextFieldDelegate. In this class I have two textfields: Password and Phone-Number. In addition, I also have two methods:
1:func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(UITextField) -> Bool
2:func textFieldDidEndEditing(UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason)

How do I associate my password textfield with the first function but not the other and vice versa? Essentially, when I set the textfields delegate, I want to be able to choose which methods gets called for each respected textfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if its the field you want to use i delegate function

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == Password {
      return true
    }
    return false
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == phoneNumber {
        // do something
    }
}
```